# Calling SQL Server's stored procedure from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

In my SQL Server database already has stored procedure dbo.usp_AddSum. I need to execute it from trigger in MySQL database. Is it possible? I know about Linked Server with MySQL but what about vice-versa?

Comment: I'd be very wary of code in a trigger that calls across databases systems. The design smells wrong.

Comment: @MitchWeat, of course you are right, but this design need support also. In case of adaptation for volatile business-logic it is not possible to correct wrong architecture solutions for more than 10 years database life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution from [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/51047/103166) and it's fine for me. It consists in to wrap stored procedure in PHP function and to call this function from MySQL by external application:

```
DELIMITER @@

CREATE TRIGGER Test_Trigger 
AFTER INSERT ON MyTable 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
DECLARE result int(10);
SET cmd=CONCAT('/usr/bin/php ', 'home/sync/send_to_sql_server.php f1=', NEW.f1, ' f2=', NEW.f2);
SET result = sys_exec(cmd);

END;
@@
DELIMITER ;
```